# Code compiles but prints unexpected "-nan"

Tags: c, cs50

Its supposed to take text and print a reading level, it seems to work except it only prints "-nan" after taking text input.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
int compute_Readability(string Text);
int compute_Letters(string Text);
int compute_words(string Text);
int compute_sentences(string Text);
float words;
float letters;
float sentences;
float Grade;
int main(void)
{
    string Text = get_string("Text: ");
    compute_Readability(Text);
    if (Grade < 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    else if (Grade > 16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }
    else
    printf("Grade:  %f\n" , (float) round (Grade));
}
int compute_Letters(string Text)
{
    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(Text); i < len; i++)
    if (isalpha(Text[i]))
    {
         letters++;
    }
    return letters;
}
int compute_words(string Text)
{
    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(Text); i < len; i++)
    if (isblank(Text[i]))
    {
         words++;
    }
    return words +=1;
}
int compute_sentences(string Text)
{
    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(Text); i < len; i++)
    if(Text[i] == '.' || Text[i] == '?' || Text[i] == '!')
    sentences++;
    return sentences;
}
int compute_Readability(string Text)
{
   float avgletters = letters / words * 100;
   float avgsentences = sentences / words * 100;
   Grade = 0.0588 * avgletters - 0.296 * avgsentences  - 15.8;
    return Grade;
}
```

This is one of my first coding projects so to be honest I'm not really sure what's going on. I've never seen -nan before so I don't really know what part of the code its coming from or what I can do to affect a different output.

Comment: `nan` is "Not a Number".  It means you've got an error somewhere in your `float` calculations.  The line `return Grade;` in a function declared as returning `int` is suspicious (though not your problem), and there are some other fishy things going on, too.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you are calling `compute_Readability` but not any of the functions that would compute the float values used there (`letters`, `words`, `sentences`).

Comment: And even those functions that try to increment those values don't actually initialize them.

Comment: What are the values of `letters`, `sentences` and `words` when `Grade` is evaluated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to call the functions you wrote. They will not magically call themselves

```
float compute_Readability(string Text)
{
   float words = compute_words(Text);
   float letters = compute_Letters(Text);
   float sentences = compute_sentences(Text);
   float avgletters = letters / words * 100;
   float avgsentences = sentences / words * 100;

   Grade = 0.0588 * avgletters - 0.296 * avgsentences  - 15.8;
   return Grade;
}
```

In all your functions you need to add local initialized counters

Example

```
int compute_Letters(string Text)
{
    int letters = 0;
    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(Text); i < len; i++)
    if (isalpha(Text[i]))
    {
         letters++;
    }
    return letters;
}
```

Remove global variables before main.

```
//float words;
//float letters;
//float sentences;
//float Grade;
```

in the `main` function add `float Grades;` as a local variable.